# Cannot format or transform data before save, bound too tightly to the view

Tags: vue.js

I have some data in `vuejs` that I want to format before sending it off through an ajax call but it changes the view its bound to. For example I have a birthday field that is formatted like this on the view `01/11/1981` but I need to format that to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` for the db and I don't want to do this on the backend.

Where and when would I do this on the frontend? I have tried doing this before the ajax request and it changes the view, so I made a copy of the data and modified it and that also changed the view. It seems no matter what I do it affects the view.

Here is my `methods` block:

````
methods: {
    /**
     * Update the user's contact information.
     */
    update() {
      /*Attempt to copy and format*/
      var formattedForm = this.form;
      formattedForm.birthday = moment(formattedForm.birthday).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');```

      Spark.put('/settings/contact', formattedForm)
          .then(() => {
              Bus.$emit('updateUser');
          });
    },
}
````

Here is my data block as well:

```
data() {
  return {
      form: $.extend(true, new SparkForm({
          gender: '',
          height: '',
          weight: '',
          birthday: '',
          age: '',
      }), Spark.forms.updateContactInformation),
  };
},
```

Comment: How did you *copy* ?

Comment: I just made a `var formattedForm = this.form` and then did my formatting and send the `formattedForm` in the `ajax` call instead.

Comment: you need to use some kind of `clone`, in js objects are passed via reference, so `formattedForm` is same object as `this.form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a clone using Object.assign, like so:

```
let form = Object.assign({}, this.form);
form.age = 21;
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y51yuf05/

Comment: Thanks that seems to be working, I can change the format and it doesn't affect the view now!

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference in javascript, which means:

```
let a = {
  "apple": 6
}

let b = a
```

then, `b` and `a` are pointing to the same location in the memory, it is essentially copying the address of the object in `a` to the variable `b`.

You need to therefore clone the object, there are many ways to do it like:

```
b = Object.assign({}, a)
```

MDN: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

this would not be deeply cloned, which means if your object is nested then the nested objects would still be linked between the original and the copy.

for which I use:

```js
function isObject(obj) {
  return typeof obj === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj)
}

function clone(obj) {
  let result = {}
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (isObject(obj[key])) {
      result[key] = clone(obj[key])
    } else {
      result[key] = obj[key]
    }   
  }
  return result
}

function logger () {
  console.log("p.a.b.c: ", p.a.b.c)
  console.log("q.a.b.c:", q.a.b.c)
  console.log("r.a.b.c:", r.a.b.c)
}

let p = {a: {b: {c: 5}}}
let q = clone(p)
let r = Object.assign({}, p)

logger()
p.a.b.c = 11
logger()
```